# Searching on multiple columns in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

How would one do the following in NHibernate?

```
    SELECT  ContactName, ContactTel1, ContactTel2, ContactTel3
    FROM tb_Contact
    WHERE (ContactTel1 LIKE '%6440%') OR
         (ContactTel2 LIKE '%6440%') OR
         (ContactTel3 LIKE '%6440%')
```

This is what I have, but can't figure out how to do the same with multiple columns.

```
  all = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Contact)).Add(Expression.Like(pField,  "6440", MatchMode.Anywhere))
                 .List<Contact>();
```

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Disjunction expression.

```
all = session.CreateCriteria (typeof(Contract))
                .Add (
                      Restrictions.Disjunction().Add (Restrictions.Like ("Tel1", "6440")
                                                .Add (Restrictions.Like ("Tel2", "6440")
                                                .Add (Restrictions.Like ("Tel3", "6440")
                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session.CreateCriteria (typeof(Contract))
                .Add (
                      Restrictions.Like ("Tel1", "6440")||
                      Restrictions.Like ("Tel2", "6440")||
                      Restrictions.Like ("Tel3", "6440")
                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the MatchMode...

```
all = session.CreateCriteria (typeof(Contact))
                .Add (
                      Restrictions.Disjunction().Add (Restrictions.Like ("Tel1", "6440", MatchMode.Anywhere)
                                                .Add (Restrictions.Like ("Tel2", "6440", MatchMode.Anywhere)
                                                .Add (Restrictions.Like ("Tel3", "6440", MatchMode.Anywhere)
                     );
```

Comment: Jesus, I don't think it is necessary to give the complete detailed code.
I think the Disjunction part of my post is the most important one to the topicstarter; that was the missing part.  He can write the remaining part of the solution himself, can't he ?  We're not monkeys, are we ...